# Which method is better for storing key value pairs in an sqlite database?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, chatbot

I'm creating a chat bot that will have it's own "memory". It will save the user's input in key-value pairs and later access that memory to see how to construct a response. The database will basically act as a dictionary that grows as the bot recieves input.

The first method would be to simply make two columns and add multiple values to the "Value" column. The value column stores multiple strings. (I'm not sure how I would even do this...) Like so:

```
 Key     | Values                 |
"i play" | "games","with","music" |
"and i"  | "run", "sleep", "like" |
```

The other method would be to have one "Key" column that corresponds to multiple values. Each value column stores one single string. Like so:

```
  Key    | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
"i play" | "games" | "with"  |"music"  |
"and i"  | "run"   | "sleep" | "like"  |
```

I know storing multiple values to one key is a big "no-no" in relational databases, so if there's a better way let me know?

EDIT: So a little bit about how the bot will create a response, it will take a key and randomly choose ONE value from the multiple values. For example, if "I play" was the chosen key, it would randomly pick a value such as "music". From there, it would find the new key called "play music" (if the key does not exist, it will construct one) and randomly select one value from the multiple values.

I've thought of maybe using an arraylist in the value column, so that it is a true "one key, one value" key-value pair, but I'm not sure if SQLite supports lists.

Comment: I generally don't like storing key-value pairs, but in some instances, they are the only choice.  If so though, I'd recommend only storing a single key with a single value.  So your first example would have 6 rows...  If you only have 3 attributes (values), then the 2nd method could work as well.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think either method is a good method.  How about this?

```
key         value
"i play"    "games"
"i play"    "with"
"i play"    "music"
"and i"     "run"
"and i"     "sleep"
"and i"     "like"
```

That is, key/value pairs should be exactly that, one row per key/value pair.  Of course, you might want additional columns to specify other information -- such as an entity id or an ordering for the multiple values.

Comment: and you have to decide what a value should be exactly. Is "games with music" really three values (or just one)?

Comment: @Thilo . . . I don't know if your question is to me or to the OP.  I think the question is clear that the those are three separate values.

Comment: Yep they're three separate values! I also added an edit to clarify that.

Comment: Oh, they are clearly three separate values in the question. I am just doubtful if that makes sense application-wise.